# AWS EB, Play Framework and Docker: Application Already running

Tags: amazon-web-services, playframework, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running a Play 2.2.3 web application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, using SBTs ability to generate Docker images. Uploading the image from the EB administration interface usually works, but sometimes it gets into a state where I consistently get the following error:

> Docker container quit unexpectedly on Thu Nov 27 10:05:37 UTC 2014:
>   Play server process ID is 1 This application is already running (Or
>   delete /opt/docker/RUNNING_PID file).

And deployment fails. I cannot get out of this by doing anything else than terminating the environment and setting it up again. How can I avoid that the environment gets into this state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you may be running into the infamous Pid 1 issue. Docker uses a new pid namespace for each container, which means first process gets PID 1. PID 1 is a special ID which should be used only by processes designed to use it. Could you try using [Supervisord](https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/) instead of having playframework running as the primary processes and see if that resolves your issue? Hopefully, supervisord handles Amazon's termination commands better than the play framework.

Answer (score 1):

@dkm was having the same issue with my dockerized play app.  I package my apps as standalone for production using '$ sbt clean dist` commands. This produces a .zip file that you can deploy to some folder in your docker container like /var/www/xxxx.

Get a bash shell into your container: `$ docker run -it <your image name> /bin/bash`

Example:  `docker run -it centos/myapp /bin/bash`

Once the app is there you'll have to create an executable bash script I called mine `startapp` and the contents should be something like this:

Create the script file in the docker container:

```
$ touch startapp && chmod +x startapp

$ vi startapp
```

Add the execute command & any required configurations:

```
#!/bin/bash

/var/www/<your app name>/bin/<your app name> -Dhttp.port=80 -Dconfig.file=/var/www/pointflow/conf/<your app conf. file>
```

Save the startapp script then from a new terminal and then you must commit your changes to your container's image so it will be available from here on out:

Get the running container's current ID:

```
$ docker ps
```

Commit/Save the changes

```
$ docker commit <your running containerID> <your image's name>
```

Example:  `docker commit 1bce234 centos/myappsname`

Now for the grand finale you can docker stop or exit out of the running container's bash. Next start the play app using the following docker command:

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 <your image's name> /bin/sh startapp
```

Example:  `docker run -d -p 80:80 centos/myapp /bin/sh startapp`

Run `docker ps` to see if your app is running.  You see something similar to this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND              CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
19eae9bc8371        centos/myapp:latest   "/bin/sh startapp"   13 seconds ago      Up 11 seconds       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   suspicious_heisenberg
```

Open a browser and visit your new dockerized app

Hope this helps...