# Getting "This application is already running", but can't find RUNNING_PIT

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, playframework

I have a play app running in a docker on AWS EB.  I rebuilt the env and now I am getting `This application is already running (Or delete /var/run file).` error.  However, I can't find the RUNNING_PID.  I checked root, as well as /opt/docker/.  I've tried `find . -name RUNNINGPID`.  I added lines to my conf to put the PID file in /var/run/ but I can't get rid of this current one because I can't find it!

Can someone please help?  Bit of a newb to this stuff.

Comment: May be it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351405/restarting-play-application-docker-container-results-in-this-application-is-alr or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27168112/aws-eb-play-framework-and-docker-application-already-running

Comment: Thanks.  I've looked at those